# in Gita whether Krishna says that 'Gita is Krishna himself'

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, identification-request

A local preacher yesterday said  that:

> In gita Krishna explicitly literally said that: "anyone believing in him should
>   believe that Bhagwad Gita is Lord Krishna Himself"

Can somebody help me in finding the verse number

Comment: not familiar with that as a verse.